# Taglocity "Clone" For Mac Outlook 2011?

Tags: ms-office

I'm a huge user of [Taglocity](http://www.taglocity.com) on Windows (Outlook 2010).  Being a recent convert to a Mac, I'm very interested in using the Outlook app from Mac Office 2011.  However, I can't get by without some at least basic functionality that I depend on from Talocity, which is Windows-only.

The most important feature is the ability to **automatically** keyword tag emails as they are sent and received **and** to have those tags follow emails that are subsequently sent/received in that thread.

Workflow is typically something like this --

1. I receive an email.  Take a look at it and **manually** tag it with the "Widget" and "Red" keywords.
2. I reply/forward that email and my response is **automatically** tagged with the same keywords.
3. A new email arrives from the same thread.  It is **automatically** tagged.
4. Rinse, repeat...

A simple keyword search/filter mechanism is needed as well.

Any ideas?  Thanks.